# Remove stopped windows service from task manager

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-services, apache-commons-daemon

Iam running a user-created windows service and it works fine. It also shows up on the task manager but when i stop this service it still continues to show in the task manager. My question-Is it possible that when the service is stopped from services panel, the service from task manager is also removed?

Comment: some thread still running?

Comment: No threads are running as it is a service so when i stop it, the service stops but still remains in the task manager

Comment: *No threads are running as it is a service* this does not make sense - check with jconsole or a similar tool

Comment: From which Task Manager tab do you wish to remove the service?

Comment: From the PROCESSES tab